# Javascript unset array

Tags: javascript, arrays, unset

How do i unset an array in javascript?
i just want to empty it - so it has nothing in it keys or anything

Answer (score 10):

you can assign a new array to it:

```
var array = ["element1","element2","element3"];
...
array = new Array();
```

OR

```
array = [];
```

Comment: This code will set the variable "array" to a new empty array. This is perfect if you don't have references to the original array "array" anywhere else because this actually creates a brand new (empty) array. You should be careful with this method because if you have referenced this array from another variable or property, the original array will remain unchanged.

you can use array.length = 0 instead.

Answer (score 6):

Assign an empty array to it

```
   x = []
```

Answer (score 4):

```
array.length = 0
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

What about delete?

```
delete array
```

Or to delete a single index:

```
delete array[x]
```

Comment: @Tadeck Of course delete doesn't work, delete is for object properties without the `DontDelete` attribute, not `var` or `function` declarations which have the `DontDelete` attribute. If you make the array an [implicit](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/k8nhe/1/) window property or an [explicit](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/k8nhe/2/) one it will work in **most** browsers (`delete` is implementation-dependent). [More info about delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#property_attributes). (but of course, this is not an ideal way to declare arrays)

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = ["elem", "item"];
...
array = []; // Empty!
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR REFERENCE (I know its old and answered)

---

If you want to empty the array, that has been [answered](/questions/2486688/javascript-unset-array/26170622#2486699) already.
If you want to **unset** the array, you could assign an unset variable...

```
var undef;
var myArr = [];
...
myArr = undef;
// typeof myArr == undefined
```